# If $A$ is nilpotent, why is $A$ non-invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Here $A$ is a square matrix. I'm confused as to why $A$ would be non-invertible as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, $A^n$ is invertible for all $n$. But $0$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 4):

Since $A$ is square and nilpotent
$$
\det (A^n) = \left( \det(A) \right) ^n = \det(0) = 0,
$$
so $\det(A) = 0$ and $A$ is singular.

Answer (score 3):

If $\,BA = 1\,$ and $\,n\,$ is least with $\,A^n = 0\overset{\large\,  B \times_{\phantom I}}\Rightarrow A^{n-1} = 0\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there were an inverse matrix $B$ such that, where $I$ is the identity:
$$AB=I$$
It follows that
$$A^nB^n= A(A(\cdots A(AB)B\cdots)B)B=I$$
But if $A^n = 0$ then
$$0B^n=I$$
$$0=I$$
Hey wait...